# time_t (mhour) operations (+ / - ...)

Tags: c++, time, int, output, operations

thank's for read, this is easy question but ... i'am surprised.

My code is :

```
/* GET THE TIME */ 

time_t theTime = time(0);
struct tm *aTime = localtime(&theTime);
int mhour = aTime->tm_hour;

ostringstream oss;
string myString = " ";

oss << mhour;
myString += oss.str(); // OKAY, OUTPUT Correct

std::cout << myString << endl;    

// But if i replace and execute this : 

oss << (mhour + 3);
myString += oss.str();// OUTPUT IS EMPTY ! Why ? How can i add +, -, * on "mhour" ?
```

**Why ? How can i add +, -, * on "mhour" ?**

Comment: Have you any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you expect your output? You don't print anything to the console the second time around.

If you put this line of code at the end of your sample:

```
std::cout << myString << endl;
```

Then the total output of your program will be (for example):

```
14
141417
```

This makes sense, as you add `oss` twice to your string, and the second time it hasn't been cleared, nor has your string.

So your value of `mhour` is increasing as you expect.